# Unable to start new Activity on button click using Intent,Logcat shows no errors

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to start an activity on button click,Current activity has 3 buttons,when a user clicks login button i need to open Login activity,this is my code

Current Activity:

```
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
```

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

```
public class Startup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Intent intent;

    Button login;
    Button signin;
    Button fb;
    private  static final int RC_SIGN_IN= 0;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);
        auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
        signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btsignin);
        fb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fb_con);


        signin.setOnClickListener(this);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                intent = new Intent(Startup.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);



            }
        });
        fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (auth.getCurrentUser()!= null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Startup.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }else {

                    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setProviders(
                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                            .build(),RC_SIGN_IN
                    );

                }

            }


        });




    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                Log.d("Auth",auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                Log.d("Auth Name",auth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();


            }
            else {

                Log.d("Auth","Not Authenticated");

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

The Loginn class doesent start and app crashes with no Real error in Logcat.

Updated Manifest
My manfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hilz.hellogreen">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <!-- <intent-filter> -->
            <!-- <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> -->


            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
            <!-- </intent-filter> -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Startup"
            android:label="Hello Green"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Orders"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE: I now notice this error in Logcat:

```
 E/SmartFaceManager: Listener does not implements SmartFaceInfoListener2
```

Comment: 'Logcat shows no errors'; You haven't registered your Activity in the manifest, so there **MUST** be an error in logcat. It should look something like this: `Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.name/com.xyz.Loginn}:`

Comment: i get this in Logcat: 05-23 17:30:10.133 905-3634/? E/SmartFaceManager: Listener does not implements SmartFaceInfoListener2

Comment: post the code for `Login` class.

Comment: Also, the `SmartFaceManager` error has nothing to do with your app, you can ignore that.

Answer (score 2):

There is typo in your code.

In the java class, you refer to `Loginn.class` and in your manifest `.Login` which are not the same.

Change `Loginn.class` into `Login.class` (which seems to be the correct spelling) and it should work.

Comment: Sorry Typo was in question only,i corrected that now i get this error:
 E/SmartFaceManager: Listener does not implements SmartFaceInfoListener2

Comment: Well, I tried your code in AS, and it works fine for me...
Did you try to make a clean build ?

I never had your error. I think it's not activity related so.

Answer (score 0):

So this hapenned after i refracted a number of classes,I got a recent clean copy from repository and tried again.Apparently this was happening because Appcompat couldnt support the themes features,Adding a NoActionBar property to the theme solved the problem